# Is it possible to define submanifold like this

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, definition

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold) offers the following definition for an (embedded) submanifold:

An embedded submanifold (also called a regular submanifold), is an immersed submanifold for which the inclusion map is a topological embedding.

I've been wondering if one could not equivalently define a submanifold like this:

$(\ast)$ Let $M$ be a smooth $m$-manifold and let $N$ be a subset. Then $N$ is an $n$-submanifold if and only if it is itself a $n$-manifold when endowed with the subspace topology.

> Is this definition equivalent to the usual definition with embedding?

**Edit!**

It appears that "my" definition is in fact common, too.

I seem to have found it in [this book on page 5](https://books.google.com/books?id=t2ibHX06oH4C&lpg=PA177&dq=Differentiable%20Germs%20and%20Catastrophes&pg=PR3#v=onepage&q&f=false):

1.5. Definition. A subset $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ is called differentiable submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ of dimension $m \le n$ if to each $x\in M$ there corresponds an invertible germ $\widetilde{\phi}:(\mathbb R^n,x) \to (\mathbb R^n,0)$ such that $\widetilde{\phi} (M,x) = (\mathbb R^m,x)\subset (\mathbb R^n,x)$ ($\mathbb R^m$ linearly embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ for $m \le n$)

> This is exactly the same as $(\ast)$ if in $(\ast)$ we let $M = \mathbb R^n$,
>   right?

Comment: Technically that is weaker even than the second condition of the inclusion map being a topological embedding...nothing says that the subspace topology can't be a different manifold topology than the original! It would also imply that the immersion condition is superfluous, which I doubt (but don't know).

Comment: The question is basically "why do we need an embedding to be an immersion?" in this definition. A pathological reason is given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1136737/192336 Basically, we want not only $f(N)$ to be a topological manifold in the subspace topology, but we also want the tangent space to behave nicely with respect to this map.

Comment: @Moya Sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: Didn't you mean to say $N$ is a *smooth* $n$-manifold?

Comment: @TedShifrin  Yes I did. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @MattSamuel "nothing says that the subspace topology can't be a different manifold topology" -- I don't understand. My "is itself a n-manifold when endowed with the subspace topology" should ensure that the subspace topology coincides with the topology of a manifold.

Comment: @Moya Oh! I think this could answer my confusion... but I need to think about it some more first.